# Suggestion on Stack Overflow's search bar

Tags: discussion, search

I was searching something in Stack Overflow's search bar, and got 0 results:

[image]

However, if I used the same words as the title of a new question, I got a long list of very good related questions/topics. But they are in a very narrow window display and also this might not be a way of "searching" that everybody is aware of:

[image]

Is it possible for Stack Overflow to bring the same or similar search function from question title to the search bar on the top?

Comment: I think this is a question better suited for meta than here, but it’s a good one.

Comment: SO's internal search is complete trash btw. If you want any type of decent search results, you're much better off with `your query here site:stackoverflow.com` in your favorite search engine

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the link. That one is informative and explains why. The advanced search types are helpful. However, I still believe there is something that can be done to improve for the normal search. One typical example is the one in my post above. For many users like me searching for something don't really care the matched words are from title, content or else. Why not order the searched results with a weighted index based on matching from title, content, and other types together? The weighted index could be complex or simple, but at least it would give some instead of 0 results.

Comment: That would be a feature-request. This question is a discussion.

Comment: @Zoe Agreed. The difference between results of the normal search and title search made me feel something like: [on title search] Don't make similar question to existing ones. We are serious! [on normal search] Search for whatever you like. Good luck! LOL